# Dotnet :- How to go back a web page using windows form app?

Tags: .net, winforms

I am developing a windows form applicaion, through which i am controlling a web site. i want to go to a previous page after navigating many pages. what approach i should take to go to a previous page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a `WebBrowser` control?

If so, the WebBrowser control contains a `GoBack()` method that may suit your needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.goback.aspx